# Incorrect buffer size in MPI

Tags: mpi

I am getting the following error output while executing MPI_Recv:

```
MPI_Recv(buf=0x000000D62C56FC60, count=1, MPI_INT, src=3, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x0000000000000001) failed
Message truncated; 8 bytes received but buffer size is 4
```

My function needs to find the number of a row which has a maximum element at the `ind` position.

My function's code is found below:

```
int find_row(Matr matr, int ind)
{
    int max = ind;
    for (int i = ind + 1 + CurP; i < N; i += Pnum)
        if (matr[i][ind] > matr[max][ind])
            max = i;

    int ans = max;
    if (CurP != 0)
    {
        MPI_Send(&max, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for (int i = 1; i < Pnum; i++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(&max, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            printf("max %d %Lf! Process %d;\n", max, matr[max][ind], i);
            fflush(stdout);
            if (matr[max][ind] > matr[ans][ind])
                ans = max;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Matr is the following type definition: `typedef vector<vector<long double> >& Matr;`

`CurP` and `Pnum` are initialized in the following way:

```
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Pnum);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &CurP);
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: What's strange about the error? It's saying it received 8 bytes but can only fit in 4

Comment: Strange beacause it works with first two processes, but crashes with the third, when they have same code

Comment: the message states `src=3` so there are at least 4 tasks. Note your program might deadlock since no recv is posted before the barrier. The issue is likely in the code you do not show, so please edit your question and add a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

It's my fail. I execute MPI_Bcast from not all processes in another part of my code.